Plot different line chart with R
I have a dataset like this:
number <- c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
val <- c(19,20,9,17,2,2,3,9,19,4,15,14,18,8,5,13,9,15,3,16,1,15,13,10,7,7,9,15,14,12)
m <- data.frame(number, val)

I want to draw different line plot, following "number" column, so I want a specific plot every time number is equal to 0. I mean:

first plot for the first 0 to 10
second plot for the second 0 to 8
third plot for the third 0 to 9

How can I do whit R?

Do they have to be separate plots or can these be all in one plot colored differently?

Different plots are better than one plot

Using cumsum on diff in INDEX of by.
> par(mfrow=c(1, sum(m$number == 0)))
> by(m$val, cumsum(c(1, diff(m$number) < 0)), plot, type='l') |> invisible()



Data:
> dput(m)
structure(list(number = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 0, 
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), val = c(19, 
20, 9, 17, 2, 2, 3, 9, 19, 4, 15, 14, 18, 8, 5, 13, 9, 15, 3, 
16, 1, 15, 13, 10, 7, 7, 9, 15, 14, 12)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-30L))


Use which to determine 0's positions and create the plots:
number <- c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
val <- c(19,20,9,17,2,2,3,9,19,4,15,14,18,8,5,13,9,15,3,16,1,15,13,10,7,7,9,15,14,12)
m <- data.frame(number, val)

w <- which(m$number == 0)
w <- c(w, length(m$number)+1)

for (i in 1:(length(w)-1)) {
  st <- w[i]
  sp <- w[i+1]-1
  plot(m[st:sp, "number"], m[st:sp, "val"], t = "l", xlab = paste("plot", i), ylab = "values")  
}


Created on 2024-04-05 with reprex v2.1.0
